# Creating an ignorable polymorphic relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphism

I am looking to create a table called `ignorables` with `ignorable_type` and `ignorable_id` where I can store IDs of different types of objects I'd like to ignore in the UI.

How can I leverage ActiveRecord's polymorphic associations to achieve this?

Comment: Have you read the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)? What have you tried so far? Add some code to your question indicating what's working and what's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say that I don't 100% get your question but this would be my take

1) you would need to create the table. I am sure you know how to do this, but this is how

`rails g migration CreateIgnores`

```
#db/migrate/20180106072916_create_ignorables.rb
class CreateIgnors < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :ignors do |t|
      t.integer :ignorable_id
      t.string  :ignorable_type
      ...
    end
    add_index :ignors, [:ignorable_type, :ignorable_id]
  end
end
```

2) now you can create your models

```
class Ignore < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ignorable, polymorphic: true
end
```

3) what belongs to the ignorable

```
class Other < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ignored, as: :ignorable
end
```

4) now last but not list  you want to do do something

```
class Other < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ignored, as: :ignorable
  validate :belongs_to_ignored
  ...
  private
  def belongs_to_ignored
    if ignored
      false
    end
  end
end
```

I hope that this can lead you in the right direction